# How to enable program to speak?

Tags: reactjs, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, voice-recognition

I am trying to create my own voice assistant with React.js, react-speech-recognition and react-text-to-speech packages. My problem is that it does not speak, just when I added button like it is in documentatiton in react-text-to-speech. I also tried to add command, if program react right and use my commands, which it does.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import SpeechRecognition, { useSpeechRecognition } from 'react-speech-recognition';
import { useSpeechSynthesis } from 'react-speech-kit';

const Dictaphone = () => {
    const { speak, cancel, speaking } = useSpeechSynthesis();
    const { transcript, resetTranscript } = useSpeechRecognition({
        commands: [
            {
                command: 'reset',
                callback: ({ resetTranscript }) => resetTranscript(),
            },
            {
                command: 'open *',
                callback: (site) => window.open('https://' + site),
            },
            {
                command: 'navigate to *',
                callback: (pageName) => {
                    window.location.href = `https://localhost:44435/${pageName}`;
                },
            },
            {
                command: 'test',
                callback: () => speak({ text: transcript }),
            },
        ],
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!speaking && transcript) {
            speak({ text: transcript });
        }
        SpeechRecognition.startListening({ continuous: true });
    }, []);

    if (!SpeechRecognition.browserSupportsSpeechRecognition()) {
        return <span>Browser doesn't support speech recognition.</span>;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => SpeechRecognition.startListening({ continuous: true })}>Start</button>
            <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.stopListening}>Stop</button>
            <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
            <button onClick={() => speak({ text: transcript })}>Read</button>
            <p>{transcript}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Dictaphone;
```

Comment: Try `tts-react`.

Comment: Why should I do it? Why is this package different?

Comment: You don't have to that's why it was only a comment.